# Foreign Key "automatic column lookup" in Django

Tags: python, sql, django

Consider the following models:

```python
class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey('Publisher')

class Publisher(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    publisher_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I would like to call `Book.objects.filter(id=123)`, but the output for this should be:

`{ 'id':123, 'title':'ABC', 'publisher':1 }` for admin users, and

`{ 'id': 123, 'title':'ABC', 'publisher':'XYZ Books' }` for normal users.

My question is, can this be done with `select_related()` or changing the `models.ForeignKey()` parameters only?

Comment: use select_related on query and modify the api response according to the user who actually calls the api.

Comment: you want publisher name for normal user right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get publisher name from book object by using `Book.objects.filter(id=123).publisher_name` if normal user otherwise call only publisher.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey('Publisher')

    @property
    def publisher_name(self):
        return self.publisher.publisher_name

class Publisher(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    publisher_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```